# picasa api - How to get a specific album with an album id?

Tags: python, django, api, picasa

How do I get a specific album from the picasa api?

Currently I am doing something like this:

```
def album(gd_client, album_id, user):
    all_albums = albums(gd_client,user)
    for album in all_albums:
        if album.service_id == album_id:
            return album
```

Which means I get all the albums and filter out the one I need.

But there must be an easier and more efficient way.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Google Data Protocol version 2.0 there is experimental support for [PartialResponse](http://code.google.com/apis/picasaweb/docs/2.0/developers_guide_protocol.html#PartialResponse), which allows you to filter responses at the server by passing in a `fields` parameter.

Unfortunately only the Java API supports 2.0, but you can easily add it to the Python API yourself.

Comment: Unfortunately not in the Python API - it is only in the Java API. You can easily add it though by [cloning the source](http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/source/checkout).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want "entry" API. Here is how I can get AlbumEntry for a public album (do not want to deal with auth):

```
base = "https://picasaweb.google.com";
user = "101405741057659770470" # myself
albumid = "6333524051829767505"
# must be inside of a function to use locals()
url = "%(base)s/data/entry/api/user/%(user)s/albumid/%(albumid)s" % locals()

gd_client = gdata.photos.service.PhotosService()

entry = gd_client.GetEntry(url)
assert isinstance(entry, gdata.photos.AlbumEntry)
```

Similar in Java:

```
String baseURL = "https://picasaweb.google.com";
String userId = "101405741057659770470" // myself
String albumid = "6333524051829767505"
String albumUrl = String.format(
    "%s/data/entry/api/user/%s/albumid/%s", baseURL, userId, albumId);
// myService is defined here: https://developers.google.com/picasa-web/docs/2.0/developers_guide_java
AlbumEntry entry = myService.getEntry(new URL(albumUrl), AlbumEntry.class, (DateTime) null /* modified since*/);
```